# Promote SharePoint News

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a good level of experience with SharePoint but I cannot find a piece of information. I am planning on generating News articles and pushing them to SharePoint based on another system we have. The part i'm not so sure on is how you get the article to be promoted to the news feed web part.

I am assuming it tags the item in a hidden list somewhere because I cannot see any metadata which would indicate the news article should be promoted.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is field called **Promoted State**.
For Page to become a News Page, PromotedState value needs to be set to 2 to display it via the news headlines web part.

Look at this link for Promoted State field

https://www.eliostruyf.com/what-makes-a-page-to-be-a-news-page-on-sharepoint-online/

Look at this link for changing Promoted State field
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Change-News-Page-to-Site-Page/td-p/181257

Comment: Cheers Marko I will take a look